# React input saving

Tags: reactjs

I have a little problem:

I have an input to give the user the possibility to upload a video file and another input to enter the title of the video. I would like to know how **to keep track of this couple(video and title)** to save it with React and to update it if he modify these inputs.
I have an idea to create a dictionary containing the title of the video as a key and the file as a value but I do not know how to implement it.

It would help me a lot  if someone has a solution for that

```js
const [videoTitle, setVideoTitle] = useState("");
const [videosrc, setVideosrc] = useState("");
const inputRef = useRef(null);
const [isUploaded, setIsUploaded] = useState(false);
const [isDone, setIsDone] = useState(false);
const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");

//to store all the couples(filevideo,title of the video)
const [allFiles, setAtllFiles] = useState();

const handleVideoChange = (event) => {
  try {
    const file = event.target.files[0];

    setIsUploaded(true);
    setVideosrc(URL.createObjectURL(file));
    setFileName(event.target.files[0].name);
    console.log("the file is: " + event.target.files[0].name);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setVideoTitle(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.onSubmit({
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
      text: videoTitle,
    });
    setVideoTitle("");
    setIsDone(true);
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a dictionary to keep track of the video and title pairs. Here's how to do it.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

const UploadVideo = () => {
  const [videoTitle, setVideoTitle] = useState("");
  const [videosrc, setVideosrc] = useState("");
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [isUploaded, setIsUploaded] = useState(false);
  const [isDone, setIsDone] = useState(false);
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");
  const [allFiles, setAllFiles] = useState({});

  const handleVideoChange = (event) => {
    try {
      const file = event.target.files[0];

      setIsUploaded(true);
      setVideosrc(URL.createObjectURL(file));
      setFileName(event.target.files[0].name);
      console.log("the file is: " + event.target.files[0].name);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleTitleChange = (event) => {
    setVideoTitle(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setAllFiles(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [videoTitle]: videosrc
    }));
    setVideoTitle("");
    setIsDone(true);
  };

  const renderFiles = () => {
    return Object.keys(allFiles).map((title) => (
      <div key={title}>
        <p>{title}</p>
        <video src={allFiles[title]} controls />
      </div>
    ));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Video Title:
          <input type="text" value={videoTitle} onChange={handleTitleChange} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Upload Video:
          <input type="file" onChange={handleVideoChange} ref={inputRef} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      {isDone && renderFiles()}
    </div>
  );
};

export default UploadVideo;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. appreciate it ! It really got me unstuck